# Swift 3 and Google Maps with Navigation Drawer

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, navigation-drawer

I am creating an application with Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.2.1. On the main screen you have the Google map in the background and you also have a "NavigationDrawer Acvtiviy". The problem is that when I make a slide to the right or left, the "side" does not appear but the map moves. How can I distinguish between moving the map and showing the right or left side?. My code en UIViewController is:

```
class MainMapVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:40.4893538, longitude:  -3.6827461, zoom: 5.5)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.mapType = .satellite 
        self.view = mapView
    }

    @IBAction func leftSideButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.centerContainer?.toggle(MMDrawerSide.left, 
animated:true, completion:nil)

    }


    @IBAction func rightSideButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.centerContainer?.toggle(MMDrawerSide.right,animated:true, completion:nil)
    }


}
```

And the code in AppDelegate is:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var centerContainer: MMDrawerController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("edcer..erc..er.erc.e.c.")


    // Override point for customization after application launch.var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewControllerlet mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController!

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainMap", bundle: nil)

    let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainMap") as! MainMapVC
    let leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController
    let rightViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightSideViewController") as! RightSideViewController

    let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
    let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
    let rightNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rightViewController)

    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(center: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav,rightDrawerViewController:rightNav)
    centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView;
    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.panningCenterView;


    window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with following one

mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false